# $q doesn't work asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am using `promise` and `$q` to make an asynchronous call. But it doesn't work.

eventData.js

```
angular.module('eventsApp').factory('eventData'  , function($http ,$q, $log) {
    return {

        getEvent : function() {

            var deferred = $q.defer()
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/springhibernateangularjs/service/events'}).
                then(
    function(response){
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                    console.log("succccccc");
                },
    function(error){

                    console.log("faiiiiiiil");
        deferred.reject(status);
                });
            return deferred.promise ;
        }
    };
});
```

EventContrller.js

```
$scope.event  = eventData.getEvent();
```

But `$scope.event` is not loading correctly!

Comment: You can also just return  `$http({method: 'GET', url:'http://localhost:8080/springhibernateangularjs/service/events'})` since that itself is a promise and delegate error handling to the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you get the data since you are returning a promise not the results:

```
eventData.getEvets().then(function(result){
       $scope.event = result;
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer` as the `$http` service already returns a promise.

```
app.factory('eventData'  , function($http) {
    return {

        getEvent : function() {
            //RETURN http promise
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/springhibernateangularjs/service/events').
                then(function(response){
                    console.log("succccccc");
                    //return to chain data
                    return response.data;
                },
                function(error){    
                    console.log("faiiiiiiil");
                    //throw to chain rejection
                    throw error;
                });
        }
    };
});
```

In the controller:

```
eventData.getEvent().then(function(data){
    $scope.event = data;
});
```